# Power supply makes a static/coil whine noise when the power supply is off and the PC is off

Tags: power-supply, mains, electromagnetic, computers, interference

I have noticed that my power supply (PSU) makes a VERY slight coil whine/static noise while it is plugged into the power outlet, regardless of the power status of the PC and the PSU. It sounds no matter what, and it is only quiet when it is not plugged in to the power outlet.

To hear this noise, you must be very close to the PSU (under 1 inch from the power supply). I am very noise conscious, so I am slightly concerned some of you may not even notice it.

The thing is, I have changed to a new PSU but the noise is still there.

Is this normal?

P.S. Apparently (not according to the manufacturer, but some online people,) the sound is normal if it’s a small humming noise, due to electromagnetic interference (harmonics introduced by appliances in the mains) or dirty power (imperfections in electrical signal by generators) and the power supply is trying to clean the power or the harmonics cause internal components to resonate at hearable frequencies. I don’t know if this is true or not. I know that it may not belong to this stack site, but I believe that this is the most appropriate stack for people who can understand and explain this phenomenon.

Comment: If you could find some USB device which draws perhaps 2 W all the time, then it *might* be that it would load the +5VSB rail from the PSU enough that it raises its frequency above what you can hear. What is the make and model of the PSU?

Comment: There are no USB devices plugged into the PC

Comment: I'm suggesting that you do plug a USB device in so that there is more current draw on the +5VSB rail. To supply more current, the convertor in the PSU needs to operate at a higher frequency, which may end up being high enough that you can't hear it any more.

Comment: That is interesting, but since the noise still happen even when PSU is turned off, the USB didn't do anything.

Comment: It seems unusual that the physical power switch on the back of the PSU would not actually switch it off. On the positive side, it will probably deter mosquitos and mice from approaching within an inch of the back of the PSU. What is the make and model of the PSU?

Comment: @AndrewMorton  MSI MAG A750GL

Answer (score 0):

The power button on the PC doesn't toggle everything off. The VAC to VDC conversion part of the PSU is always active until you physically pull out the wire or flip the power switch at the back of the PSU. Also, the power button just turns off *most* of the VDC rails, but not all of them - there will be standby voltages.

If the PSU has EMC immunity problems, then you may experience "coil whine". Unfortunately this is kind of normal and it is harmless as far as product performance goes. Most often it is probably not the 50/60Hz mains causing it, but more likely some higher frequency radio device, maybe a WiFi router or a wireless headset etc.

> the power supply is trying to clean the power or the harmonics cause internal components to resonate

This is hogwash however, the power supply always tries to do that, whether there's coil whine or not. The coil whine is not a byproduct of "cleaning the voltage", it's simply caused by poor design. It may as well be caused by some traces picking up radiated disturbances not coming from the mains at all. Coil whine does very likely occur when exposed to specific EMI frequencies though.

Although harmless, it does mean that the PSU is non-conforming. Since a PC is a device which may play audio, then the PSU emitting audible noise means it shouldn't pass EMC testing, since the audio-generating product does evidently not work as intended when exposed to EMI.

Lots of crap on the market manages to get past that EMC test somehow, probably by enlisting fishy test houses. My previous PSU from Corsair, a so-called premium PSU, had this problem too - in my case a certain frequency emitted from the GFX card caused PSU coil whine. I'd call it non-conforming junk failing to meet CE/FCC etc regulations.

> The thing is, I have changed to a new PSU but the noise is still there.

Yeah I wouldn't expect otherwise, since this is very likely a product design problem and so switching to an identical PSU of the same brand won't solve anything.

Comment: You mentioned that the some part of the PSU is still on while the PC is off. But what about when the PSU is off (the power switch on the PSU is off) and is off for awhile (no residual) and PC is off. For me, it still sounds when both is off. 
Is it the same explanation (some of the psu is still ‘on’ even psu itself is off)? 

Also, I have tested the PSU at my office. There is no coil whine noise while it’s on or off. So is it really the PSU now?

Comment: @P.Z. If you pull out the power cord and wait 5 minutes, then it should be completely powerless and the only thing still alive then is some coin cell battery on the motherboard driving BIOS clock and such (quite an unlikely culprit and should hold no coils either).

Comment: I see. So as long as the power cord is in the PSU, non-conforming PSU could still generate coil whine, regardless of the PSU/PC is on or off ?  The PSU does not sound after the power cord is pulled out. But as soon as it is plugged back in, the sound will be back.

Comment: @P.Z. Are you sure that's the power switch and not a switch for the fan?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Please see updated thread for the photo of the PSU state while it’s generating the coil whine

Answer (score 0):

Many depends on coils quality and operating point (electrical and so magnetical) where is core hold.

Whether core is glued, how tight are winding wounded.

From electrical perspective whether core is hold at the edge of saturation or windings are under high current stress an so creating a force.

I even met a whistled resonant capacitor.